Convert JPG image into WSQ image compression using NBIS on iOS
I need to convert and compress fingerprint images to the WSQ (Wavelet Scalar Quantization) format. WSQForAndroid is online availabe code which is working fine on android but I'm having wrong output in iOS for same input which i'm providing to android.
Can you please tell me where might be issue or how to achieve this on the iOS platform? Thank you!
